# Angular website fails on iOS 16.5 or newer

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome, safari

Devices with iOS 16.5 or later no longer work on our website https://next.dk/beregn/nybil/1/indtast-nummerplade

Our test device is in Danish but it says something along the line of "There are repeating problems with "https://next.dk/beregn/nybil/1/indtast-nummerplade?basketId=..." on Safari. Chrome will just say that the page cannot be shown.

We found that if you disable the experimental setting (Safari) "next-generation inline layout integration (IFC)" it works again, but it's no use since we can't get our customers to do that. For some reason that setting is on as default at least in iOS >=16.5. If you have an Apple device with iOS <16.5 it would be helpful if you can check what the setting is set to or if it exists at all!

The website is using Angular 12.0.4 with a mix of bootstrap and Angular material components.

If you Google "next-generation inline layout integration" there's no help in understanding what it is and what it does. Does anyone know?

This is not an issue on Android or PC.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce that issue on a supported version of angular ? (v15/v16). That way you could report it to the Angular team !

Comment: I would post it to 'WebKit' slack channel as well. If it is an issue in 'IFC', which is upcoming Layout changes in Safari, it would be good to get it fixed.

Comment: Just to flag, I have reported it to respective WebKit engineer working on IFC as part of Next Generation Layout. You can learn about it from here: [Next Generation Layout - Meta Bug on Bugzilla][1]


  [1]: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215087

Comment: We have Angular 16.1.8 and we are having issues with at least iOS 16.6. Our site randomly hangs. It does not happen on Safari on a Mac or Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While checking with WebKit engineer working on IFC, it was confirmed that it was fixed in following commit:

https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/9d3c89bfe30cee221fa647c3599cc8b0d033fbd5

But following bug is raised to add related test case for better coverage in future:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=259251

---

Apple does not comment on when the following commit will make to public release but just to confirm, it has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. It looks like a fix is out now. We ended up hiding the Angular component, which caused our site to break on IOS, but it seems to no longer be an issue so we will revert that change.

Comment: We are still having issues with iOS 16.6. Perhaps is an unrelated issue but it’s just on iOS on mobile

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas - This patch is not yet merged in Safari releases (as far as I know), so can't help much. Might be something to test again with Safari 17 or iOS 17 release.