# AdSense causing my Angular 16 site to freeze

Tags: angular, adsense, angular-ssr

I have had Google AdSense for quite a while now and everyting has been working fine in my Angular app. That however has changed in the past few days where I have noticed on mobile devices the site was freezing when I had AdSense running. I could prove that was the root cause of the issue because if I don't enable them the site works like a charm however I have them enabled I get either blank page screen (total or partial) or the site hangs.

I have tested that behavior on a PC, a Mac, old iPads, various iPhones and an Android phone. On PC it works on Chrome without a problem however I could reproduce the issue on Edge. The site hangs but nothing is displayed in the console. On old iPads I could not get ads rendered therefore the site works as expected (considering the compatibility issues due to the versions of Safari). When tested on a Mac I got it working on both Safari and Chrome. Trying on iOS 16.3 and 16.6 I could reproduce the problem and I could see the site working when rejecting the analytics and marketing cookies. Android with new OS didn't show any issues either however I don't have the exact version. Old versions of Android seem to have the problem as well. If you want to test the behavior you can check https://www.micarburante.com .

My site is currenly on version 16.2.0 and the TS config is configured this way:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

My package.json has the following packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^11.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^16.2.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^12.0.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/express": "4.17.17",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "20.4.8",
    "concat": "1.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "11.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.8.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-scss": "4.0.6",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.9.0"
  }
```

I don't have anything fancy on my build process - only running `PurgeCSS` to reduce the `style.css` file size.

The AdSense configuration is pretty standard and I don't really know what could be happening. I checked this in case it could be related [Angular website fails on iOS 16.5 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76659792/angular-website-fails-on-ios-16-5-or-newer/76696159#comment135582884_76696159) but I have the latest version of iOS and still doesn't work. I also updated to the Angular 16.2.0 just in case but it didn't work either. I tried to set the TS config to be for ES2020 or ES2015 to see if it was related to incompatibility in terms of JS - ignoring if that could possibly be.

The last thing I tried was to disable, completely, client hydration so that my `main.ts` looks like this:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { bootstrapApplication, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation, withInMemoryScrolling, withRouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import routes from './app/app.routes';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        provideHttpClient(),
        provideAnimations(),
        provideRouter(routes, 
            withInMemoryScrolling({
                scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
                anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
            }),
            withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation(),
            withRouterConfig({
                paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always',
                onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
            })
        ),
        //provideClientHydration()
    ]
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

and my `main.server.ts` looks like this (I have my entire application configured to use only standalone components and I have SSR in place as well):

```
import { bootstrapApplication, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import routes from './app/app.routes';

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        provideHttpClient(),
        provideRouter(routes),
        provideServerRendering(),
        //provideClientHydration(),
    ]
});
export default bootstrap;
```

The actual freeze happens when you navigate to the home page and scroll all the way down to the bottom of it and click either a link in the related links (something for example "Gasolineras en Madrid") or you click any element of the footer.

Comment: Hi Carlos. I tried reproducing on iOS 16.6 but it works fine. When you reproduce on Edge - do you see anything interesting in console logs before the site breaks? I'm guessing once it freezes - devtools become unresponsive and you can't inspect anything?

Comment: Hi Mikita, I wasn’t able to get anything in the console prior the application breaks. On iOS 16.6 I was able to reproduce by scrolling all down very quickly and click ok one of the footers links

Answer (score -1):

There is infinite loop, you can open devtools and hit pause in debugger to see where it happens and which code is responsible.

Comment: Hi Kemsky, thanks for this. How do you know there is an infinite loop? Could you clarify how did you see that?

Comment: When page hangs, use pause to see which code is executing, do that several times and you will see that it is the same code, a loop that never ends.

Comment: I found there was a HostListener being executed by mistake which I fixed. I managed to get that working and in development I can see no more infinite loops. When I run the Ads though I still can see the code hanging on mobile devices however I don't know what is happening now. Stopping on Edge (my best bet since I don't have iOS & Mac) I can see something Ad-related...not sure where to look now

Comment: you can attach debugger to mobile webview and try the same approach

Comment: I could try on Edge and the only difference I see compared to Chrome is that the "scroll" event is fired. In Chrome that does not happen. This is coming from the polyfills file so I am not sure if that's something related to my code? Like I say, before the fix I was getting in Chrome a scroll event fired because I had it set up incorrectly. Now I am handling it with RxJs and that's gone and tested. You reckon I will get anything different in the debugger?

Comment: Would you be able to try yourself and let me know if you are still getting the same code hit as before?